# Java regular expression to find text

Tags: java, regex

my input paragraph consist a road that end with road or avenue (e.g melbourne road or Negombo Kimbulapitiya Road). Can any one suggest me a pattern type to extract the road name from paragraph?

Comment: What constitutes a road name?

Comment: there is a missing word in your question after "with", or your punctuation is wrong.

Comment: it is a descriptive location of a house, from that i need to extract road name only.

Comment: how can you know when the non road name part ends and the road name part starts?

Answer (score 1):

If your `String` always ends with `' Road'`, you could just remove the 5 last characters.-

```
String res = road.substring(0, road.length - 5);
```

Comment: my actual paragraph consist not only this road name. it consist other stuffs also(example:-  300m to Biyagama Road, 2Kms to Kelaniya Temple, 500m to Water world.)

Comment: Mmh that`s a whole different scenario indeed. I'm affraid can't find a matching pattern at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex

```
"(?i)\\s*(road|avenue)\\s*$"
```

It matches - case insensitively `(?i)` - the words `road` or `avenue` at the end of a line `$` and - just for trimming - any spaces `\\s*` before and after it.

```
@Test
public void extractRoadOrAvenueName() {
    String regex = "(?i)\\s*(road|avenue)\\s*$";

    String road = "melbourne road".replaceFirst(regex, "");
    Assert.assertEquals("melbourne", road);

    road = "Negombo Kimbulapitiya Road  ".replaceFirst(regex, "");
    Assert.assertEquals("Negombo Kimbulapitiya", road);

    String avenue = "sunset Avenue".replaceFirst(regex, "");
    Assert.assertEquals("sunset", avenue);
}
```